# hyperlinking from listed months in YearArchiveView

Tags: django, django-views

I have a YearArchiveView page which shows a list of months within the year.  I am trying to set up hyperlinks from each month to a page for that month which lists all the activity in the month.

I cannot shake off the following error message:

> NoReverseMatch at /booking/2014/
>
> Reverse for 'booking-month-archive' with arguments '(u'2014/01',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['booking/(?P\d{4})/(?P\d{2})/$']

My views.py:

```
class BookingsThisYear(YearArchiveView):
    
    queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    date_field = 'start_date'
    make_object_list = True
    allow_empty = False
    allow_future = False

    
class BookingsThisMonth(MonthArchiveView):
    
    queryset = Booking.objects.all().order_by('start_date')
    date_field = 'start_date'
    make_object_list = True
    allow_empty = False
    allow_future = False
```

urls.py:

```
    url(r'^booking/(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 
        BookingsThisYear.as_view (
        template_name = 'guests/booking_archive_year.html'),
        name = 'booking-year-archive'),
    
    url(r'^booking/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/$', 
        BookingsThisMonth.as_view (month_format='%m'),
        name = 'booking-month-archive'),        
        )
```

and my template code:

booking_year_archive.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block col1 %}
<div class="col-md-12">
    
    {% for date in date_list %}
        {% if date_list %}
            <a href="{% url 'booking-month-archive' date|date:'Y/m' %}"> </a>{{ date|date:"M" }} | </a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

</div><!--col-md-12-->
{% endblock %}
```

booking_month_archive.html

```
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <h3>{{ month|date:"F Y" }}</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th style="width 30%">Dates</th>
            <th style="width 30%">Name</th>
            <th style="width 40%">Comments</th>
        </thead>
            {% for obj in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ obj.start_date|date:"F j, Y" }}</td>
                <td>{{ obj.guest }}</td>
                <td>{{ obj.notes }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  I should say that when I enter 'booking/2014/07' in the url bar it loads the month_archive_view.html page perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'2014/01'` is one argument. Your view expects two --> `'2014'` and `'01'`

Try

```
{% url 'booking-month-archive' year=date|date:'Y' month=date|date:'m' %}
```

`{% url %}` will convert that to `booking/2014/01`

Answer (score 0):

Since your view expects two arguments, a year and a month and not one date string you could either send the month and date as keyworded arguments in your `{% url %}` tag

```
{% url 'booking-month-archive' year='2014' month='7' %}
```

or normal positional arguments

```
{% url 'booking-month-archive' '2014' '7' %}
```